# Mongoose and nested arrays

Tags: mongoose

My Schema

```
let citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
});
let countrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   regions : [{
      cities : [ref: 'City']
   }]
});
```

The problem - how to insert existing city into a selected (by _id) region. The _id of a region is automagically added by mongoose/mongodb, and I do not want to change it, as it should remain stable.

I currently tried various combinations of `findOneAndUpdate` but in vain. My current query:

```
Country
   .findOneAndUpdate({
     _id : knownCountryId,
     'regions._id' : knownRegionId
    },{
        $push : { 'regions.$.cities' : existingCity._id }
    },{
       select : {
           'regions' : {
               $elemMatch : {
                    _id :  knownRegionId
               }
           }
       }
    }).exec();
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findOneAndUpdate` query is correct. The problem was in the test, which was caching an outdated value of the `Country` object.